# Good K/M/G abbreviation of y scale labels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, format, axis-labels

#### Question

How can we *easily* have Kilo/Mega/Giga labels without "bits" or "Bytes" unit symbols?

#### Example

```r
data.frame(x = LETTERS[1:5], n = c(0, 5000, 10000, 15000, 20000)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, n)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::number_bytes_format(units = "si"))
```

[image: y scale with Kb instead of K]

For the y scale I expect the labels `0K`, `5K`, `10K`, `15K`, `20K`. No `Kb`!

#### Bonus question

Is there any available solution to get `0`, `1K`, `1M`, `1G` labels? I.e., the most appropriate abbreviation of the values?

Comment: Alternative, divide by 1000, and label y as "n (Kb)" ?

Comment: I do not know the magnitude of the scale. Il may be K, it may be M or even G. By now, all I want is to get rid of the `"b"` in the `"Kb"`

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29787452/680068

Comment: From related post: `gdata::humanReadable(n, standard = "Unix", sep = "")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `gdata::humanReadable`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gdata)

myDat <- data.frame(x = LETTERS[1:5], n = c(0, 5000, 10000, 15000, 20000))

ggplot(myDat, aes(x, n)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = myDat$n, 
                     labels = humanReadable(myDat$n, standard = "Unix", sep = ""))
```

[image]

---

**Edit:**

We could customise the function:

```
humanReadableCustom <- function (x, units = "auto", standard = c("IEC", "SI", "Unix"), 
                                 digits = 1, width = NULL, sep = " ", justify = c("right", 
                                                                                  "left")) 
{
  #suffix.SI <- c("B", "kB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB")
  # custom
  suffix.SI <- c("", "K", "M", "G", "T", "P", "E", "Z", "Y")

  suffix.IEC <- c("B", "KiB", "MiB", "GiB", "TiB", "PiB", "EiB", "ZiB", "YiB")
  suffix.Unix <- c("B", "K", "M", "G", "T", "P", "E", "Z", "Y")
  standard <- match.arg(standard)
  if (length(justify) == 1) 
    justify <- c(justify, justify)
  .applyHuman <- function(x, base, suffix, digits, width, 
                          sep) {
    n <- length(suffix)
    i <- pmax(pmin(floor(log(x, base)), n - 1), 0)
    if (!is.finite(i)) 
      i <- 0
    x <- x/base^i
    if (is.null(width)) 
      x <- format(round(x = x, digits = digits), nsmall = digits)
    else {
      lenX <- nchar(x)
      if (lenX > width) {
        digits <- pmax(width - nchar(round(x)) - 1, 
                       0)
      }
      if (i == 0) 
        digits <- 0
      x <- round(x, digits = digits)
    }
    c(x, suffix[i + 1])
  }
  if (any(x < 0)) 
    stop("'x' must be positive")
  if (standard == "SI") {
    suffix <- suffix.SI
    base <- 10^3
  }
  else if (standard == "IEC") {
    suffix <- suffix.IEC
    base <- 2^10
  }
  else {
    suffix <- suffix.Unix
    base <- 2^10
  }
  if (!missing(units) && units == "bytes") {
    retval <- rbind(x, "bytes")
  }
  else if (!missing(units) && units != "auto") {
    units <- suffix[match(toupper(units), toupper(suffix))]
    power <- match(units, suffix) - 1
    X <- x/(base^power)
    X <- format.default(x = X, digits = digits, nsmall = digits)
    retval <- rbind(X, rep(units, length(X)))
  }
  else retval <- sapply(X = x, FUN = ".applyHuman", base = base, 
                        suffix = suffix, digits = digits, width = width, sep = sep)
  if (all(justify == "none")) 
    paste(trim(retval[1, ]), trim(retval[2, ]), sep = sep)
  else paste(format(trim(retval[1, ]), justify = justify[1]), 
             format(trim(retval[2, ]), justify = justify[2]), sep = sep)
}
```

Then plot

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gdata)

myDat <- data.frame(x = LETTERS[1:5], n = c(0, 5000, 10000, 15000, 20000))

ggplot(myDat, aes(x, n)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = myDat$n, 
                     labels = humanReadableCustom(myDat$n,
                                                  standard = "SI", sep = ""))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this is not exactly what I want • `standard : character, "IEC" for powers of 1024 ('MiB'), "SI" for powers of 1000 ('MB'), or "Unix" for powers of 1024 ('M'). See details.` • I want powers of 1000 ('M') and possibly using g (grams), m (meters) as unit instead of b (bits)

Comment: @Costin See edit, we can steal the code and update to our needs.

Comment: If we steal, I prefer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1094933/2107667 :) Thank you, @zx8754

Comment: @Costin No problem, it is just an idea, you can customise as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

`gdata::humanReadable` doesn't work with negative numbers, it adds the suffix B to numbers below 1000, and it adds one digit after the decimal point to all numbers, and it uses 1024-byte kilobytes if you specify `standard="Unix"` instead of `standard="SI"`:

```
> gdata::humanReadable(-10,standard="Unix",sep="")
Error in gdata::humanReadable(-10, standard = "Unix", sep = "") :
  'x' must be positive
> gdata::humanReadable(2500,standard="Unix",sep="")
[1] "2.4K"
> gdata::humanReadable(2500,standard="SI",sep="")
[1] "2.5kB"
> gdata::humanReadable(10,standard="SI",sep="")
[1] "10.0B"
```

You can use `scale_y_continuous(labels=kimi)` with this function:

```
kimi=\(x){
  e=floor(log10(abs(x)))
  e2=pmax(e,0)%/%3+1
  suf=c("","k","M","B","T")
  x[]=ifelse(abs(x)<1,x,paste0(round(x/1e3^(e2-1),ifelse(e%%3==0,1,0)),suf[e2]))
  x
}

kimi(c(-2.3e9,-12345,-12,0,50,200,2235,12345,126583,125467080))
```

```
 [1] "-2B"    "-12.3k" "-12"    "0"      "50"     "200"    "2k"     "12.3k"
 [9] "127k"   "125M"
```